# TYPO3 looking for portfolio and comment extension, thats running together

Tags: plugins, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Im new in TYPO3 v. 6.1 / FLUID / EXTBASE, but learning..
I have designed a homepage that show some soccer drills bc. im a soccer coach.

I need to show the drills like a portfolio where the user can see:

- Image or Video.
- Short info text.

and when the user then click the image/video, then the "Item" is showed with some more info.

and then i need a comment plugin thats works with facebook, so the user can comment a drill, but need to login before he/she can add a comment.

Now my question is, is there someone here that know or have experience with a plugin/extension that provide both Portfolio and comment or know two great plugins/extension that works together.

Comment: Can someone plz. tell me why this question is giving -1, is it a bad description or is it not OK to ask this question, feedback will be fine so i know it till the next question.

Comment: I don't know exact reason for -1, but, probably because it is not really related to programming. Regarding your question, you may try [news extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news) or [tt_news](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tt_news). It is not portfollio really, but there you have a list and single views. Also there are additional extensions to add comments.

Comment: Hi Viktor, okay and thx, but if TYPO3 and Extensions for TYPO3 is not "Relateded" programming, what will it then be related to.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the ext. news from Georg Ringer & comments from Ingo Renner

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news/
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/comments

How have to be work this with "Facebook"?

greetings
maty

Comment: Hi Matthias, with Facebook I think - that the user some how login and the can add a comment, so its not open for spammers.